# ¿Como saber cuando termina Map, Reduce, y filter?

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, map

¿Cual es la mejor manera de saber cuando termina el recorrido de un array en javascript con alguna de estas funciones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para map y filter puedes utilizar el segundo parámetro del callback que indica el indice del elemento actual.

Para reduce utiliza el tercer parámetro del callback.

```js
let arreglo = [1,2,3];
arreglo.map((elemento, indice) => {
     if(indice == arreglo.length - 1)
       console.log("Soy el último: " + elemento);
     return elemento;
})

arreglo.filter((elemento, indice) => {
     if(indice == arreglo.length - 1)
       console.log("Soy el último: " + elemento);
     return true;
})

arreglo.reduce((acumulador, valorActual, indice) => {
     if(indice == arreglo.length - 1)
       console.log("Soy el último: " + valorActual);
     return acumulador + valorActual;
})
```